# Maven Asciidoctor plugin and external images directory

Tags: maven, asciidoc, asciidoctor

We have a single-sourcing structure for building a few AsciiDoc documents. Some of the builds use Maven with the AsciiDoctor plugin; this is a requirement from the dev tean.

But we need a shared images directory (a requirement from another build). And we don't want to use symlinks in the repository so that people can do local builds on Windows.

The way we do it now is by pointing to imagesdir in the asciidoctor plugin config in pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <imagesDir>${project.basedir}/../../_images</imagesDir>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

While the build works, it fails to copy the images into `target/generated-docs` . Instead the images are referenced in their existing place.

How can I make the Maven build properly copy those images and have references in the HTML file to the copy inside generated-docs? I could certainly write a post-processing script, but there must be some way of doing it inside Maven?..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the resource plugin to copy over all images. Add this to your build:

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/asciidoc/images</directory>
                <targetPath>../generated-docs/images</targetPath>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Please adjust the folder names accordingly. Use `filtering` set to `false` as images are binary files and you don't want Maven to do substitutions here.

Depending on your setup you might no longer need a `imagesDir`. The imagesDir will only specify the location of the images relative to the created HTML file. Therefore it should always be a relative URL. Your example will contain an absolute URL.